# Export CLOB Data using Shell Script

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus, clob, spool

I am trying to export CLOB data from tables . I am trying to export the data and store it in a txt file.

There are multiple related questions and I have almost tried everything but I am unable to achieve it . The data gets exported only upto 4000 characters.

Below is my trail :--

```
 test.sql

 SELECT  A.ID , DBMS_LOB.substr(A.USERS,32767) , DBMS_LOB.substr(B.NAME,32767)
 FROM TEST A , TABLE B
  WHERE
    A.ID = B.ID;

test.sh
  
  #!/usr/bin/bash
   FILE=test.txt
   nohup sqlplus SCMH/PWD@DB << EOF

   set colsep ","
   set headsep off
   set pagesize 0
   set trimspool on
   set linesize 30000
   set numw 15
   SET BUFFER 30000

   SPOOL $FILE
   @test.sql
   SPOOL OFF
   EXIT
   EOF
 exit
```

I am able to export the data as mentioned but only 4K characters are coming . The total data in CLOB is much more than 4K.

The CLOB data is single line data e.g abc;xyz;..........

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Regards

Comment: You need to [`SET LONG ....`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-61E0AB01-A2C4-4AAE-97C7-C5D8BE5DE1BF) and [`SET LONGCHUNKSIZE ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-2033D143-DCEA-4A86-AB7B-3FE0892195FA) for LOB processing

Comment: This is the header I use to export `dbms_sql_monitor` result as a pure HTML file: `SET serveroutput OFF
SET LONG 1000000
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1000000
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIM ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF`

Comment: A SQl statement can only handle character fields of 4000 or less. When it is processing a clob, it is processing a pointer, not the clob itself. When you try to extract 32767 characters, only the first 4000 will be returned. Check out DBMS_LOB.CLOB2FILE (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-006129FC-1335-4B9F-9D9A-40130F6D6F45) if you want to export a clob to a file system file.